# Looking for the html view of the rich text field within contentful, as creating text lacks control and generates unwanted markup

Tags: contentful, richtext

I'm wondering if there is a html view within the rich text field of contentful because i cannot find it
I am getting a lot of unwanted markup as you can see in the image and want to have some more control by editing the html directly.

[image: contentful rich text field]